# file_put_contents - не загружает все картинки

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с file_put_contents.
С удаленного сервера качаю картинки и загружаю их себе. Всё ОК, но как только в названии картинки, будет присутствовать тире, то картинка не загружается.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
file_put_contents(urldecode($image));
```

Кстати, возможно просто функция не та, для скачивания, вроде file_get_contents.  :))